# In iOS 9, why are SKNodes blurry?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, scenekit

I have a SceneKit game that I'm developing. In iOS 9, when SceneKit's depth of field is turned on, `SKNodes` on the 2D Overlay scene are blurred.

This code even blurs the 2D overlay node, but none of the others:

```
// focal blur.
[DDCamera sharedCamera].camera.zNear = 1;
[DDCamera sharedCamera].camera.zFar = 100;
[DDCamera sharedCamera].camera.focalDistance = 25;
[DDCamera sharedCamera].camera.focalSize = 25;
[DDCamera sharedCamera].camera.focalBlurRadius = 50;
```

`DDCamera` is a subclass of `SCNNode` that allows other classes to manipulate the camera. Its position is `(0, 0, 25)`.

I put in a `SKNode` on the overlay scene, like this:

```
title = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithText:[DDCommonFunctions getLocalizedStringFromKey:@"title"]];
title.fontColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
title.fontName = DDDefaultFont;
title.fontSize = 100.;
title.position = CGPointMake([DDCommonFunctions getScreenSize].width * .5, [DDCommonFunctions getScreenSize].height * 0.75);
title.name = @"title";
title.alpha = 1.;
title.zPosition = 0.;

[self addNode:title];
```

Every other node I put into the scene isn't blurry, but the only `SKNode` there is blurred. Why is this?

Also, why didn't this behavior occur in iOS 8.4.1?

---

**EDIT:** a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

---

**EDIT 2:** It works as expected in OpenGL. Why not Metal? How would I get the camera to focus on the 2D scene?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot?

Comment: Have you tried to set Render API to Open GL ES in Storyboard->GameViewController->SCNView? From your screenshot I see that now you use Metal.

Comment: @JohnTracid not yet. It defaults to Metal. Why would Metal blur the label?

Comment: @DDPWNAGE this could be a reason why it works in iOS 8.4. So you could try to switch Rendering API to Open GL ES.

Comment: @JohnTracid switching from Metal to OpenGL ES makes the label no longer blurry, at a cost. It used to run at 40 FPS, now it runs at 20.

Comment: On real device or simulator?